# Create a new column with an array of column names based on condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to create a new column in a Bigquery table. This new column values must be an array of the colour column names based on a condition.
My table "Users" looks like:

| User | Red | Blue | Green | Yellow | Other columns not related |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |  |
| Second | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |  |
| Third | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |

and the expected table or view must be something like this:

| User | Red | Blue | Green | Yellow | Array_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | Red, Blue, Yellow |
| Second | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | Green |
| Third | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | Red, Blue |

I am relatively new to SQL and Bigquery sintax, I've tried creating a view and also with

```
ALTER TABLE myproject.mydataset.users`
```

and I get the column names with this:

```
SELECT column_names
FROM `myproject.mydataset`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE (table_name = 'users')
```

But I can't find how to create the array list and make a column with them. I'm crashing against a wall.

Comment: Do you know before the column names? They never change?

Comment: Yes, the column names are  always the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  regexp_extract_all(translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', ''), r'(\w+):1') as Array_col
from mytable t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Hi Mikhail! Thanks for your answer it seems pretty straightforward and It works fine but if I just need 3 columns and not the all of them? I should put this premise on the question and now I have realized my mistake... sorry! I will accept your answer anyway

Comment: this is not consistent with your previous comments on other answer - where you ask about selecting all/100/200 columns. in my answer you don't need to do so - it will take all columns which have 1 as a value!

Comment: Sorry but I was asking for 200 rows not columns. I'm trying to understand the code. Maybe I misunderstood the explanation. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be ok:

```
with mytable as (
  select 'First' as user, 1 as Red, 1 as Blue, 0 as Green, 1 as Yellow union all
  select 'Second' as user, 0 as Red, 0 as Blue, 1 as Green, 0 as Yellow union all
  select 'Third' as user, 1 as Red, 1 as Blue, 0 as Green, 0 as Yellow
)
select *, split(trim(if(Red=1, 'Red', '') || if(Blue=1, ' Blue', '') || if(Green=1, ' Green', '') || if(Yellow=1, ' Yellow', ''), ' '), ' ')
from mytable
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, thanks for your answer. I have a few questions: this code works just with the sample table but will it works with 100 rows? should i write selects for all rows?

Comment: 100 rows - no problem, 100 columns would make this sql to look ugly

Answer (score 0):

Now you can try super new syntax for BigQuery! Let's do this with `UNPIVOT` statement:

```
WITH mytable AS (
  SELECT 'first' AS user, 1 AS Red, 1 AS Blue, 0 AS Green, 1 AS Yellow UNION ALL
  SELECT 'second' AS user, 0 AS Red, 0 AS Blue, 1 AS Green, 0 AS Yellow UNION ALL
  SELECT 'third' AS user, 1 AS Red, 1 AS Blue, 0 AS Green, 0 AS Yellow
)
SELECT t.*, Array_col FROM (
    SELECT user, ARRAY_AGG(color_name) Array_col FROM mytable 
    UNPIVOT(check_color FOR color_name IN (Red,Blue,Green,Yellow))
    WHERE check_color = 1
    GROUP BY user    
)
JOIN mytable t USING (user)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Sorry if I look too noob but I'm trying to understand the code, if I have to use it on a table with 200 rows and users, should i put the 200 selects???

Comment: It will works for any number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, the column names are always the same ...

In case if you want to consider only those 4 columns - check below

```
select t1.*, 
  array(select color from t2.colors where value = 1) Array_col
from mytable t1, 
unnest([struct([struct<value int64, color string>
  (Red, 'Red'), (Blue, 'Blue'), (Green, 'Green'), (Yellow, 'Yellow')
] as colors)]) t2
```

Comment: Thank sagain Mikhail!